# Populate ListView only once on fragment with FragmentTabHost Nested Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, fragment-tab-host

I'm developing an app which has a ListView on a Fragment, I'm getting some data from SQLite using AsyncTask and filling a ListView, but every time i switch between the tabs, the ListView is populated all over again, it's not getting all the data again, but it is putting on the List again...

Is there a way to stop that? I want that my ListView is populated only once when i create the fragment. i am using Android ActionbarSherlock Nested Fragment Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to detach fragment an then attach again once you return to that tab, instead of remove fragment and create again.